# How to replace space with space pipe and space?

Tags: editor, atom-editor

I am writing documentation on GitHub. Tabular data needs to be represented on the Github page. For that one has to use pipe.
Below is the sample data:

```
SalesAgent  SalesCountry    SalesAmount
Tom UK  200
John    US  180
John    UK  260
David   India   450
Tom India   350
```

This should be converted into tabular data that should be represented on Github page.

```
|SalesAgent|SalesCountry|SalesAmount|
|----------|------------|-----------|
|Tom    |UK |200|
|John   |US |180|
|John   |UK |260|
|David  |India  |450|
|Tom    |India  |350|
```

The same process needs to done for several tables.
So one quick hack I thought of is to replace `space` with  `space pipe and space`.
Tried replacing a space in atom and notepad++ editor. But it is not working.
How to do that using atom text editor. Please suggest, if there is any other text editor that does it more efficiently.

Comment: Is that the format you meant to have? What is the search & replace you did, and what format did you end up with / what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) to format GitHub Flavoured Markdown tables correctly. There are several ways to do so: [CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettier), [web](https://prettier.io/playground) or using an [Atom plugin](https://atom.io/packages/prettier-atom) (note that there are [several others](https://atom.io/packages/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=prettier&commit=Search) to choose from).

The following example uses the CLI version of Prettier, but the result should be the same with any other version.

```
$ cat example.md
|SalesAgent|SalesCountry|SalesAmount|
|----------|------------|-----------|
|Tom    |UK |200|
|John   |US |180|
|John   |UK |260|
|David  |India  |450|
|Tom    |India  |350|

$ npx -q prettier example.md
| SalesAgent | SalesCountry | SalesAmount |
| ---------- | ------------ | ----------- |
| Tom        | UK           | 200         |
| John       | US           | 180         |
| John       | UK           | 260         |
| David      | India        | 450         |
| Tom        | India        | 350         |
```

Please note that I'm using [npx](https://github.com/npm/npx) to execute it once without installing. If you prefer, you can also install `prettier` globally and directly use `prettier example.md`.